# Do the regular expression in notepad++ or Visual Studio editor can replace multi-line to auto increment number?

Tags: regex, notepad++

for instance, change the following(multi-line):

```
hello-a
hello-b
hello-c
hello-d
```

to

```
hello-1
hello-2
hello-3
hello-4
```

I just find regex "hello-[a-zA-Z]*" to match "hello-?", but can't find a replacement replace them to auto-added numbers.

Comment: Do you need `a` to always be replaced by `1`? For example, if there was another `hello-a` at the bottom of the list, would this item become `hello-1` or `hello-5`?

Comment: no, the begin number and end number can be set by myself better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I'm not yet sure about **`Notepad++`**, but</strike> for **`Textpad`**, you use:

```
\i(n)    -or-
\i(n,)   -or-
\i(n,m)
```

in your case **`\i(1)`** or just **`\i`**.

Also, in the example regex you provided:
**`hello-[a-zA-Z]*`**

It would match (as you have mentioned):

```
hello-a
hello-b
hello-c
hello-d
```

but it would also match "hello-a...a" ("hello-" followed by one or more alpha):

```
hello-aa
hello-abc
hello-tuvwxyz
```

and it would also match "hello-" (when followed by nothing or followed by non-alpha):

```
hello-
hello-#
hello-1
```

So, if this is as you intended it, the Regex search would be:

```
(hello-)[a-zA-Z]*
```

If you want to match "hello-" followed only-one alpha, the Regex search would be:

```
(hello-)[a-zA-Z]
```

If you want to match "hello-" followed one-or-more alpha, the Regex search would be:

```
(hello-)[a-zA-Z]+
```

For all these, the Regex replacement would be:

```
\1\i(1)
```

---

The basic syntax is:

```
\i[(n[,m])]
```

n is the starting point, and m is the increment amount.

```
\i(100,5) --> 100,105,110...
```

If parenthesis are not specified (\i by itself), this is the same as \i(1) or \i(1,1)

```
\i --> 1,2,3...
```

If parenthesis are specified...

If n is omitted then n defaults to 0.

```
\i(,1) --> 0,1,2...
\i(,100) --> 100,200,300...
```

If ",m" is omitted, then m defaults to 1.

```
\i(1) --> 1,2,3...
\i(101) --> 101,102,103...
```

If both n and m are omitted [\i() by itself], this is the same as \i(0) or \i(0,1)

```
\i() --> 0,1,2...
```

Note: in order for **`\i`** to work properly, you have to **`Replace all`** on the entire document (or the entire selection).

There is no **`ending`** parameter. **`\i`** will keep incrementing the replacement until all matches have been replaced.

---

It appears this is not supported in **`Notepad++`**.

Comment: hi, thank you for your detailed reply, I think I want "(hello-)[a-zA-Z]*" for my purpose.But I can't understand "\1\i(1)". Could you explain it exactly if I want a begin number and ending number?

Comment: hi, I have tested it in Textpad, the replacement "\i" works well, but I still have no idea about "\i(1)". What is this "(1)"?

Comment: @user2268680 - I have updated the answer to explain the ways to use **`\i`** in **`Textpad`**. Also, I installed the current version of **`Notepad++`**, and I couldn't find a way to perform this function in **`Notepad++`**.